# O(n^2) algorithm for computing vector product

Tags: big-o, linear-algebra

Give an O(n^2) algorithm for computing C=(xy^T)^k where x and y are n-vectors.

I have not been able to figure out how to do this and any tips would be appreciated.  all i have is

```
c=0
for i=1:n
   c=c+x(i)*y(i)
end
   c=c^k
```

Comment: What's `T`? Is `^` supposed to be exponent?

Comment: @chiliNUT `^T` (as in `T` in the exponent) is a common notation for the transposed of a vector/matrix. So `x y^T` here is the scalar product of `x` with `y`.

Comment: How is `k` supposed to depend on `n`? I don't see what is wrong with your algorithm. Assuming `k` is a constant, your algorithm is `O(n)`, so also clearly `O(n^2)`. Note however that what you are showing is the *scalar product*. The *vector product* is usually another name for the [*cross product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).